# Starting Index of the Most Frequent Consecutive Number Algorithm

Tags: python, algorithm, frequency

1) The purpose of the code: I have coded an algorithm, which is supposed to give me the exact number, which is the most frequent and consecutive at the same time number.

2) What I have tried: I have tried to write the whole code, and actually managed to get that exact number. I have also added the frequency of that number, which is the output.

3) What I need: I am looking for the algorithm, which will identify the first starting index of those consecutive numbers. For example, if the input is 123777321, as an index number 3 is needed, the reason being 777 is the most frequent consecutive number in this input, it should find its "index", and also print it out.

The Code I have written:

```
def maxRepeating(str):
    length = len(str)
    count = 0

    result = str[0]
    for i in range(length):

        current_count = 1
        for x in range(i + 1, length):

            if (str[i] != str[x]):
                break
            current_count += 1

        if current_count > count:
            count = current_count
            result = str[i]

    print("Longest same number sequence is of number {} by being repeated {} times in a row, with the first index starting at {}".format(result, count, i))



inputString = str(input("Please enter the string: "))

maxRepeating(inputString)
```

Example of an input: Please enter a string: 123777321

Example of an output: Longest same number sequence is of number 7 by being repeated 3 times in a row, with the first index starting at  **3**

Comment: What is your question ?

Comment: The code, which will get the first/starting index of the 7's in this case, as it the most frequent and consecutive number.

Comment: Your actual code isn't working ?

Comment: It does, but does not return the index value.

Comment: I need the part, which will return the index

Comment: Your algorithm is highly inefficient running in O(N^2) time

Comment: What would you prefer to run it in an efficient way?

Comment: This can be done in O(N), using a single loop and checking if the current element is equal to the previous one

Comment: @Cid thanks for informing, I will definitely edit that to that version, but still would also be better if you could share that version with us so, other will also be able to have the most efficient way.

Comment: @WOOSAL try doing it yourself, that will improve your skills

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add a variable to track the starting index of the best sequence.

```
def maxRepeating(str):
    length = len(str)
    count = 0
    result = str[0]
    start_ind = None

    for i in range(length):

        current_count = 1
        for x in range(i + 1, length):

            if (str[i] != str[x]):
                break
            current_count += 1

        if current_count > count:
            count = current_count
            result = str[i]
            start_ind = i

    print("Longest same number sequence is of number {} by being repeated {} times in a row, with the first index starting at {}".format(result, count, start_ind))



inputString = str(input("Please enter the string: "))

maxRepeating(inputString)
```

Comment: That is exactly what I needed! Thanks, in advance, appreciate it !

Answer (score 0):

From your comments, I assume you are trying to get the index at which the most frequently occurring element starts right?
Declare another variable like `max_index` and update it each time you update `count` and use that to print the index.

```
.....
max_index = 0
for i in range(length):

        current_count = 1
        for x in range(i + 1, length):

            if (str[i] != str[x]):
                break
            current_count += 1

        if current_count > count:
            count = current_count
            result = str[i]
            max_index = i
print("Longest same number sequence is of number {} by being repeated {} times in a row, with the first index starting at {}".format(result, count, max_index))
......
```